# Include path in c_cpp_properties not working in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to compile a library in C++ for embedded projects using VS Code.
I have set up a few files and can compile the library without issue. The problem comes in with my include path.

My folder structure is:

```
root
|-.vscode
|-inc
| |-hal
| | |-esp32
| | | |-pin.h
| | | |-eeprom.h
|-src
| |-hal
| | |-esp32
| | | |-pin.cpp
| | | |-eeprom.cpp
```

When I include "pin.h" in "pin.cpp", I get an error when I include it directly. I need to include it via:

```
#include "./../../../inc/hal/esp32/pin.h"
```

In my c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "esp32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/inc/hal/esp32/**",
            "${workspaceFolder}/inc/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/Users/user/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r1-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++98",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64",
        "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

Is there another setting I'm missing that is causing this? From my understanding, I should be able to (at best) include "pin.h" directly or (at worst) "inc/hal/esp32/pin.h", but neither of these work.

Additional information:
launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "espidf",
      "name": "Launch",
      "request": "launch"
    }
  ]
}
```

settings.json:

```
{
    "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/.",
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled"
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

edit:
taks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Note that `c_cpp_properties.json` is only for Intellisense. It does not set the include path for building. You need to set the include path for building in your arguments of your `tasks.json`

Comment: @drescherjm I have tried that as well. But I can't get it to work. I generate the task.json file, still compiles. I've looked at a lot of posts and articles and none of them give a solution that works. Do you have any suggestions? I have the default tasks.json file but will edit the post to add it.

Comment: Your edit did not set the include path in your tasks.json. I was expecting a `"-IfolderToInclude", ` added to your args:

Comment: I tried this on Windows and it works.  Why is your compiler path different in c_cpp_properties? Shouldn't it be clang or set your intellisenseMode to gcc-arm64?

Comment: @boocs The reason it looks different is because I'm using a Mac, and I'm compiling for a specific processor, so I want to compile with that compiler. But I tried making both of them the same (clang++) and still not working

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, my edit was incorrect. I thought I hadn't added the task.json file initially, thats why my edit adds it. The reason why you don't see the "-IfolderToInclude" property there, is because I couldn't get it working. Tried may different ways of implementing but none of them worked. Also looked if I could find any documentation for "-IfolderToInclude", but couldn't find any references for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass each include path to the compiler with the "-I" flag before each path in the args section of your tasks.json file.

```
"args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "-I",
            "${workspaceFolder}/inc/hal/esp32/",
            "-I",
            "${workspaceFolder}/inc/"
        ],
```